# Are there .Net/C# web frameworks similar to Play! Framework for Java?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, playframework

I played around with ASP .Net MVC 2 a few years ago. It was a nice MVC framework.

Right now, I'm discovering [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) for Java/Scala, and it rocks much more than I remember ASP .Net MVC rocking (ASP.Net MVC 2 wasn't bad, don't get me wrong, but Play! seems to offer much more out of the box).

Is there a a C#/.Net based web framework that is similar to Play! in terms of usability/convenience/documentation/support... ?

(I won't go into details about why Play! is so great, you can [read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597086/any-experience-with-play-java-web-development-framework) - my short personal experience has been great so far).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your looking for [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy)

Comment: Play! looks very interesting! But I'm not really sure what it offers more out of the box than ASP.NET MVC: ASP.NET MVC3 + Razor + Entity Framwork + SQL CE or SQL Server + all other libraries you need (T4MVC, StructureMap/Ninject/..., ...) conveniently via Nuget.

Comment: @marapet - the thing is it just works out of the box, and has very good documentation & support. Is there a .Net project that has this level of integration out of the box? That does't require people to already know a bunch of different frameworks, but rather JustWorks™ (and allows you to configure and tweak whatever you want)?

Comment: It does appear to do what ASP.net MVC does, but in Java. That said, Microsoft have really been a let down with documenting MVC. The original framework was so well documented, with howto's, etc. For MVC you need to go hunting through blogs to find out how it works.

Comment: Why all the close votes?

Comment: StackOverflow should add no-index no-follow for these non-answered closed questions. This *question is interesting* and it's a shame it appears first in search results.