# Java web framework with RESTful JSON services, HTML5 & jQuery ajax

Tags: java, jquery, json, html, rest

It is almost year 2013, HTML5 age. jQuery is the de-facto standard for web Javascript-ing.

This link was good for year 2010:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882082/rest-json-web-services-java-ee-framework

I am looking for **Java web framework** that will expose domain classes via RESTful JSON web services. Then will [hopefully] generate web forms for those domain classes. And uses jQuery ajax to communicate with server for sending/receiving JSON data and populate in HTML.

All web UI processing should be in client browser. Server should just transmit **static HTML5 pages**. No server-side processing like JSP.

UPDATE. I must clarify that my question point is not what framework to use for web-services creation. (There are a lot like Apache CXF, Spring MVC web services). It is not also about jQuery or not. But **Java** framework that will save time for boilerplate coding of client-server communication.

Groovy & Scala are great things, but they are not Java, but JVM languages.
(Imagine telling your teammates "We should learn Java-like language with some differences to start using a new framework." )

Bottom line:

**Java web framework** + **static HTML5 pages** + JSON interaction

Comment: You're looking for [Play Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597086/any-experience-with-play-java-web-development-framework). My answer was tongue-in-cheek. Look at the [AMD pattern](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) (with RequireJS, Backbone.js). Web apps can and should focus as much on the way the client is controlling things. My experience has been a lot of server-siders (nothing wrong with that) don't quite get how *modern* a browser and *Javascript* is these days. [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.org), [ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/). Nice.

Comment: Oh yeah, and [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) With GWT, you could use [ExtJS GXT](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/examples/). That desktop app is pretty slick. And you also got [RestyGWT](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html).

Comment: One more possibility is [TIBCO General Interface (GI)](http://www.generalinterface.org/). This system is very interesting, if you're building a complex client-side data-driven domain-controlled distributed app. Not sure if I got enough ten dollar words there, but don't be fooled, lots of sophistication here; more than I've had the need to use. I think it was developed mostly for enterprise stock/finance/commodities trading platforms. See: "MVC in the client", IDE, integration testing, etc., with DWR/Hibernate on the server. See: http://www.generalinterface.org/docs/display/DOC/Learning+Center

Answer (score 2):

Did you trying exploring Spring for domain-rest mapping and Grails's Scaffolding ? Try exploring these links to achieve your goal :

1. [Domain mapping to REST endpoint](http://java.dzone.com/articles/restful-web-applications)
2. [More on domain rest antipattern](http://www.jroller.com/rickard/entry/the_domain_model_as_rest)
3. [Generate whole application using domain model using scaffolding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html)

Comment: Thank you. I know Groovy is great, but I need Java.

Comment: Groovy is an internal DSL on top of Java. It gels with Java very well. Ultimately compile groovy files are .class files only

Answer (score 2):

Your right it is almost 2013 why not just expose your Rest Web Services with [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/)!

If your adamant about Java then look at Spring MVC as an alternative to Jax-RS. With Spring (and Jackson for JSON marshall/unmarshall) you can do something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resource")
public class ResourceController
{
    @Autowired
    private ResourceService resourceService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Resource getResource(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        return resourceService.lookup(id);
    }
    ...
}

public class Resource
{
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("resourceName")
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any *Java* web framework, that would take care of authoring static HTML5 and JavaScript.

For server-side there are Apache CXF, Spring MVC, and a lot other frameworks, that support RESTful web services.